# C++ Builder: Unit1.h(28): E2141 Declaration syntax error

Tags: c++, c++builder, syntax

C++ Builder.
Всем привет. Помогите, что я сделал не так? Вот код кнопки:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
       Edit1->Text = "Generating...";

       Sleep(700);

        randomize();
        a=random(9);
        b=random(9);
        c=random(9);
        d=random(9);
        e=random(9);
        f=random(9);
        g=random(9);
        h=random(9);
        i=random(9);
        j=random(9);
        k=random(9);
        activationkey = char(a) + char(b) + char(c) + char(d) + char(e) + char("-OEM") + char(f) + char(g) + char(h) + char(i) + char(j) + char (k);
        Edit1->Text = activationkey;

}
```

Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: 1) используйте C++ Builder в 2019 2) копипастите 3) используете [не ахти какой рандом](https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25) для генерации ключа

Comment: Где вы получили ошибку? В какой строчке кода? Что такое `a`, `b`, `c` и т.д.? Что такое `activationkey`? Что такое `char("-OEM")`??? O_o

Answer (score 0):

Язык С++ не допускает приведения указателей к целочисленным типам, если целевой целочисленный тип имеет недостаточный размер. У вас в коде такое приведение делается в `char("-OEM")` (в рамках предположения, что ваша платформа не является экзотической).

Comment: Спасибо, но это же фейк-генератор, не приносящий никакого вреда.
Edit:
a, b, c.. - цифры ключа, например: 12345-OEM6789[10][11].
Ты имел ввиду чтобы я не использовал randomize(); или C++ Builder?
Получал ошибку на последней строчке кода (Edit1->Text = activationkey;)